# Change Keras Model variable

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tensorflow2.0

I want to gradually increase a coefficient in a Keras model, that is used in calculating the loss. The variable value is based on current epoch. However, when I want to set the value, I get the following error:

`float object has no attribute dtype`

My code:

```
def warm_up(epoch, logs):
    new_value=  tf.keras.backend.variable(np.array(1.0, dtype=np.float32), dtype=tf.float32)
    tf.keras.backend.set_value(model.variable1, new_value)

callback = tf.keras.callbacks.LambdaCallback(on_epoch_begin=warm_up)

model.fit(..., callbacks = [callback])
```

How can I change a variable in a custom Keras model during training? I am using Tensorflow 2.2.

Traceback:

```
\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\training.py in _method_wrapper(self, *args, **kwargs)
     64   def _method_wrapper(self, *args, **kwargs):
     65     if not self._in_multi_worker_mode():  # pylint: disable=protected-access
---> 66       return method(self, *args, **kwargs)
     67 
     68     # Running inside `run_distribute_coordinator` already.

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\training.py in fit(self, x, y, batch_size, epochs, verbose, callbacks, validation_split, validation_data, shuffle, class_weight, sample_weight, initial_epoch, steps_per_epoch, validation_steps, validation_batch_size, validation_freq, max_queue_size, workers, use_multiprocessing)
    836       for epoch, iterator in data_handler.enumerate_epochs():
    837         self.reset_metrics()
--> 838         callbacks.on_epoch_begin(epoch)
    839         with data_handler.catch_stop_iteration():
    840           for step in data_handler.steps():

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\callbacks.py in on_epoch_begin(self, epoch, logs)
    347     logs = self._process_logs(logs)
    348     for callback in self.callbacks:
--> 349       callback.on_epoch_begin(epoch, logs)
    350     self._reset_batch_timing()
    351 

c:\Users\..\training.py in warm_up(epoch, logs)
    379 def warm_up(epoch, logs):
    380     test =  tf.keras.backend.variable(np.array(1.0, dtype=np.float32), dtype=tf.float32)
--> 381     tf.keras.backend.set_value(model.variable1, test)
    382 
    383 

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\backend.py in set_value(x, value)
   3349           (of the same shape).
   3350   """
-> 3351   value = np.asarray(value, dtype=dtype(x))
   3352   if ops.executing_eagerly_outside_functions():
   3353     x.assign(value)

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\backend.py in dtype(x)
   1266 
   1267   """
-> 1268   return x.dtype.base_dtype.name
   1269 
   1270 

AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'dtype'
```

EDIT: I changed my code to the following:

```
class LossCallback(tf.keras.callbacks.Callback):
    def __init__(self):
        super(LossCallback, self).__init__()
        self.model.beta_x = tf.Variable(1.0, trainable=False, name='weight1', dtype=tf.float32)

    def on_epoch_begin(self, epoch, logs=None):
        tf.keras.backend.set_value(self.model.beta_x, tf.constant(0.5) * epoch)

    def on_epoch_end(self, epoch, logs=None):
        logs = logs or {}
        logs['beta_x'] = tf.keras.backend.get_value(self.model.beta_x)
```

I still get an error in the `on_epoch_begin`: `'NoneType' object has no attribute 'beta_x'`.

Comment: Can you add complete traceback?

Comment: See updated post.

Comment: In your function `warm_up` you do not return anything, so you cannot write afterwards `on_epoch_begin=warm_up`.

Comment: You should do something like [this](https://pastebin.com/EC6SBnXy).

Comment: @tornikeo I tried that as well, still returns the error ```'NoneType' has no attribute 'beta_x' ```. I don't know why I can't access self.model in the init(), but I can access it in ```on_epoch_begin```

Comment: Ah, that *is* a good caveat. You can't access `self.model` in the __init__ because the model is still uninitialized when callback's `__init__` is called. That's quite easy to forget.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT 2:
When I initialize my model first and add it as an extra parameter to the callback method it works. So the solution is as follows:

```
class LossCallback(tf.keras.callbacks.Callback):
    def __init__(self, model):
        super(LossCallback, self).__init__()
        model.beta_x = tf.Variable(1.0, trainable=False, name='weight1', dtype=tf.float32)

    def on_epoch_begin(self, epoch, logs=None):
        tf.keras.backend.set_value(self.model.beta_x, tf.constant(0.5) * epoch)

    def on_epoch_end(self, epoch, logs=None):
        logs = logs or {}
        logs['beta_x'] = tf.keras.backend.get_value(self.model.beta_x)

model = create_model() # initialize custom keras model
callback = LossCallback(model)

model.fit(..., callbacks=[callback])
```

Thanks to @tornikeo for the great help!

Answer (score 0):

Avoid directly editing the variables.
You must access keras variables like this

```py
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
import numpy as np

def warm_up(epoch, logs):
    val = keras.backend.get_value(model.optimizer.lr)
    val *= 1.1
    tf.keras.backend.set_value(model.optimizer.lr, val)
    

callback = tf.keras.callbacks.LambdaCallback(on_epoch_begin=warm_up)

model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
    keras.layers.Dense(10, 'relu'),
    keras.layers.Dense(1, 'sigmoid')
])

model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy')

X_train = tf.random.uniform((10,10))
y_train = tf.ones((10,))
model.fit(X_train, y_train, 
          callbacks = [callback])
```

Notice how I get the current value like `val = keras.backend.get_value(model.optimizer.lr)`. This is correct way to get the correct value during runtime.
Also, Do not use or declare new variables inside of a loop. You probably can get a `new_value` from reading and changing the old one.
Also, avoid using any other library aside from tensorflow inside of callbacks, especially if your callbacks are going to get called often. Don't use numpy, use tensorflow. There is virtually always a tensorflow opertaion that does what you need.

Edit:
If you have some custom value to update, you can use a pattern like this:

```py
class LossCallback(tf.keras.callbacks.Callback):
    def __init__(self):
        super(LossCallback, self).__init__()
        self.someValue = tf.Variable(1.0, trainable=False, name='weight1', dtype=tf.float32)

    def on_epoch_end(self, epoch, logs=None):
        tf.keras.backend.set_value(self.model.loss.someValue, self.someValue * epoch)
```

Or you could still try to use a lambda callback.
From within the callback you can access any variable of the model. Like this `self.model.someVariable`. You can also access any custom variables that are defined in your model's custom `__init__` function like this:

```py
#in model's custom __init__
def __init__(self, someArgs):
    ...
    self.someArg = someArgs
    ...

#in callback's "on_epoch_..." method
    ...
    keras.backend.set_value(self.model.someArg, 42)
    ...
```

Note that **you can't use `self.model` in callback's `__init__`** function as the model is still uninitialized when the callback's `__init__` is called.

Does this help?

Comment: Thank you, and the code that you provide is working for me. However, I do not want to change the learning rate, but some other variable of the custom model (coefficient for loss value). When I access this variable, like ```model.variable```, I still get the same error : ```'float' object has no attribute 'dtype' ```. Which Tensorflow version are you using?

Comment: Tensorflow 2.3.0, the current latest release.

Comment: Try the updated answer, did it solve your problem? You could also use the same approach to edit any `keras.loss.someVariableName` variable.

Comment: I really appreciate your effort, but I still can not get it working. I need to access the model variables that I initialize in my custom keras model ```__init__()```, because I use these variables for my custom loss function later. With your ```LossCallback``` I can not use the ```self.weight``` variable. Also when printing the variable ```self.weight``` on the progres bar using ```logs[var] = tf.keras.backend.get_value(self.weight)``` I get the error ``` unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'NoneType' and 'int' ```

Comment: No problem, I'm here to help. Review the answer once more.